# Remove white space from levelplot plotting Google map

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, levelplot, rastervis

I'm trying to get rid of some white space produced by levelplot in the rasterVis package.  I'm using the dismo package to get a Google map, then using levelplot to plot it.  However, there is a thin strip of white around the map.  How do I remove that white space?

```
library(dismo)
library(rasterVis)

g_map = gmap(extent(c(-79,-58,36,50)),type="satellite",zoom=7,lonlat=TRUE,scale=1)


g_map_lv = levelplot(g_map,maxpixel=ncell(g_map),col.regions=g_map@legend@colortable,at=0:255,panel=panel.levelplot.raster,interpolate=TRUE,colorkey=FALSE,margin=FALSE,scales="sliced")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer rows and columns of the `g_map` object are `NA`. For example:

```
g_map[1,1]
```

You can remove them with `trim` before plotting:

```
g_map <- trim(g_map)
```